# Having issue with adbexecTimeout

Tags: android, appium, robotframework, appium-android

I'm facing a problem with adbexecTimeout using Robot Framework Appium library when testing a native web app. The test continues till the landing page and after that, it stops in the emulator. 
Also, is there any way we can use **Run Keyword If** keywords in Appium? If *YES* then how?

I tried increasing the timeout to 150000 but still, the test doesn't continue after landing screen.

I tried importing **SeleniumLibrary** for **Run Keyword If** but it got clashed with **click element** keyword

```
This is the config.robot file

*** Settings ***
Library  AppiumLibrary  run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot
Library  String
Resource  ../PageObjects/Chrome.robot

*** Variables ***
${APPIUM_SERVER}  http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
${ANDROID_PLAT_NAME}  Android
${ANDROID_PLAT_VER}  8.1
${DEVICE_NAME}  emulator-5554
${PACKET_NAME}  com.android.chrome
${ACTIVITY_NAME}  com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main

*** Keywords ***
Begin Web Application Test
    open application  ${APPIUM_SERVER}
    ...  platformName=${ANDROID_PLAT_NAME}
    ...  platformVersion=${ANDROID_PLAT_VER}
    ...  deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}
    ...  adbExecTimeout=150000
    ...  automationName=Appium
    ...  noReset=false
    ...  appPackage=${PACKET_NAME}
    ...  appActivity=${ACTIVITY_NAME}
    ...  avdLaunchTimeout=150000
    set appium timeout  60s
    sleep  5s
    tap  ${ACCEPT_CONTINUE}
    sleep  5s
    tap  ${NEXT}
    sleep  5s
    tap  ${NO_THANKS}

End Test
    close application
```

```
This is my test file  login.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource  ../../Config/input_data.robot
Resource  ../../PageObjects/LoginScreen.robot
Resource  ../../PageObjects/LandingScreen.robot

Suite Setup  Begin Web Application Test
Suite Teardown  End Test

*** Test Cases ***
Successful Login
    go to url  https://www.crediwatch.org
    tap  ${TRANSLATE_CLOSE}
    tap  ${HAMBURGER_ICON}
    tap  ${MY_DASHBOARD}
    input text  ${USERNAME}
    input password  ${PASSWORD}
    tap  ${SIGN_IN}
    wait until page contains  ${SEARCH BAR}
```

The actual result is:
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without res
ponse',))': /wd/hub/session/546570ad-c81e-433b-b563-bd4034c3ffa3/screenshot

Comment: `Run keyword if` is a built-in keyword. It should work the same no matter what other libraries you have imported.

Comment: thanks for the update and can you help me out with adbexecTimeout as well